# How to get the state names and city names from yahoo weather India using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, rss, yahoo, weather

how to extract state and city names from yahoo weather(http://in.weather.yahoo.com/india/) using C# and also get present temperature all should be in the list or as an dataset.
any clue on that would be high appreciated please

Answer (score 0):

You can use HtmlAgilityPack to scrape the data from the site.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx